# Get different name for post method

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I have an issue with my PHP code. I have a table with data from database. In the table I have an input which contain name property. When I've already loading the data from database, The property name have the same value. So, If I want to post them it only take the last input name. Here is my code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Table PHP</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="execute.php" method="POST">
     <table>
        <tr>
           <th>No.</th>
           <th>Registration Number</th>
           <th>Customer Name</th>
           <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
        <?php
    include "connect.php";
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT numreg,name FROM registration WHERE (numreg NOT IN(SELECT validation FROM tablevalidation)) ");
    $no = 1;
    while($result = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        echo "
        <tr>
            <td>$no.</td>
            <td><input type='hidden' name='numreg' value='$result[numreg]' />$result[numreg]</td>
            <td>$result[name]</td>
            <td><input type='submit' name='validation' value='Validation' /></td>
        </tr>";
        $no++;
    }
?>
     </table>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

With that code above, input name='numreg' will produce the same value for each input tag. So, if I use POST method in my form only the last record will execute even if I choose the first record. I suspect this because of the input tag property name have the same value. So, How can I get different property name in my input tag to fix my problem? Please help.

Comment: change input type name numreg to another name than try

Comment: Thanks for suggest @Darji Jigar, but I don't think it can resolve my problem because even if I change the input name numreg into another name it will remain the same. I use while loop to loading data from database so, the result will be like this: <td>1.</td><td><input name="numreg"/></td>,<td>2.</td><td><input name="numreg"/></td>,<td>3.</td><td><input name="numreg"/></td>.

Comment: Have you tried below answer? @Mike.Drinkwater

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code. You need to define numreg as array so it will display all records in post. Change `name='numreg'` to `name='numreg_".$no."'` so it will define your unique numreg for all.

```
 <html>
  <head>
    <title>Table PHP</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="execute.php" method="POST">
     <table>
        <tr>
           <th>No.</th>
           <th>Registration Number</th>
           <th>Customer Name</th>
           <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
        <?php
    include "connect.php";
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT numreg,name FROM registration WHERE (numreg NOT IN(SELECT validation FROM tablevalidation)) ");
    $no = 1;
    while($result = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        echo "
        <tr>
            <td>$no.</td>
            **<td><input type='hidden' name='numreg_".$no."' value='$result[numreg]' />$result[numreg]</td>**
            <td>$result[name]</td>
            <td><input type='submit' name='validation' value='Validation' /></td>
        </tr>";
        $no++;
    }
?>
     </table>
     **<input type='hidden' id='totalRecords' name='totalRecords' value='<?php echo $no; ?>' />**
    </form>
  </body>
</html>

<?php

if($_POST['validation'])
{
    for($i=1;$i<=$_POST['totalRecords'];$i++)
    {
        **echo $_POST['numreg_$i']."<br>";**
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Try above change in your code and give your positive feedback @Mike. Drinkwater

Comment: Can you please specify your output and desire output. @Mike.Drinkwater

Comment: How can  it will display all records in post.?

Comment: here is my code using code above:
<td><input type='hidden' name='numreg[]' value='$result[numreg]' />$result[numreg]</td>
if(isset($_POST['validation'])){
$count = count($_POST['numreg']);
$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO validation where numreg = '$count' ");
}
 The desire output I want is if I validation the first data row it execute the first data. Not the last data. With my code above with input name="numreg" it always execute the last data because I suspect it have the same name property value.

Comment: I have edited code please check it. @Mike.Drinkwater

Comment: how can I use that code above to insert data into database.? @ Ruchish Parikh. Like this.? $numreg = $_POST['numreg'].?

Comment: You need to use it with $_POST['numreg_1'],$_POST['numreg_2'],$_POST['numreg_3'] .... and so on. @Mike.Drinkwater

Comment: Good suggestion @Ruchish Parikh. But I think it will be difficult if the amount of data is much that I have to declare them one by one. Is there a way doing it ($_POST['numreg_2']) dynamicly.?